# Graph of $1/\zeta(n)$ where $n$ runs through positive real numbers .

Tags: functional-analysis, graphing-functions, riemann-zeta

Can we get a graph of $(1/\zeta(n))$  for $n$ belonging real numbers ?

I know that as

$n \rightarrow \infty$

$\zeta \rightarrow 1$

i.e. it is asymptotic to 1

but what is an exact graph looks like ?

( Only root of the equation is $n=1$ in the given domain )

Comment: Em. Yes we can?

Comment: Then what's it looks like ? Any link ? Or any image?

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1%2Fzeta%28n%29+from+0+to+10

Comment: Thank you @Wojowu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reciprocal of the Riemann zeta function has been plotted, for example [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RiemannZetaFunction.html), at the bottom of the page, e.g., $\frac{1}{\zeta(x)}$ for real $x\ge 1$.

The linked article on the Riemann zeta function is interesting in itself and has several other nice graphs included.

Comment: Thank you @Dietrich Burde

Answer (score 1):

For $s > 1$ and by analytic continuation for $s>  0$
$$\zeta(s) = \frac1{s-1}+\sum_{n=1}^\infty (n^{-s}-\int_n^{n+1} x^{-s}dx)$$

Thus for any $N \in \Bbb{Z}_{\ge 2}$ and for all $s > 0$
$$ |\zeta(s)-\sum_{n=1}^N n^{-s}-\frac{(N+1)^{-s}}{s-1}| =|\sum_{n=N+1}^\infty \int_n^{n+1} \int_n^x s t^{-s-1}dtdx|
\le \int_{N+1}^\infty sx^{-s-1}dx \le (N+1)^{-s}$$

> This is enough to plot $1/\zeta(s)$ for $s > \epsilon$

Comment: @renus thank you very much sir

Comment: Someone keep downvoting my posts . Withing 2 minute someone downvoted three quarters of my posts ???